# Error at top of post previews but not when published

Tags: php, memcached

I recently started getting this error at the top of wp post previews, but it’s not there once published:

```
warning: session_start(): Cannot find session save handler "memcached" - session startup failed
 in /home/o72k0l4cmwhy/public_html/wp-content/themes/enfold/config-templatebuilder/avia-shortcodes/portfolio/portfolio.php on line 50
```

I went to CPanel (shared server and PHP 8) enabled memcached and it caused a fatal error, so disabled it again and whilst not fatal again, the error still shows on draft post previews.

Robert

Comment: Btw site seems to be fine apart from this